# How to best to secure data over HTTPS

Tags: ssl, encryption, hash, https, diffie-hellman

My aim is to have an (iOS) app in which the user would login, then on sucsessful login, gain access to additional information over an  encrypted webservice (undecided).

From research, i understanding encryption techniques of diffie-hellman key exchange, and 'signatures' using HMAC with secret key (from the diffie-hellman).

Further research lead me to HTTPS to ensure no-eavesdropping.

However i'm now a little confused as to what i would need to do over the HTTPS connection to ensure that the login data is secured between app & server.

**1)**, is HTTPS enough security to pass POST 'username' & 'password' data down the line to the server on its own? or would an additional security such as a hash of the password be needed?

or

**2**, would i need to implement a full key exchange + request signature (and at some point an Access Token), over a HTTPS connection?

I'm unsure where to draw the line with encrypting.

Comment: This kind of question belongs to security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Moved: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71516/how-to-best-to-secure-data-over-https